# How to create multi-level dictionaries easily

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to create a nested dictionaries like the example below:

```
rule={}
rule["exports-rule-info-2"]["pathname"] = qtree_name
rule["exports-rule-info-2"]["security-rules"]["security-rule-info"]["read-write"]["exports-hostname-info"]["name"] = security_rules 
rule["exports-rule-info-2"]["security-rules"]["security-rule-info"]["root"]["exports-hostname-info"]["name"] = security_rules
rule["exports-rule-info-2"]["security-rules"]["security-rule-info"]["sec-flavor"]["sec-flavor-info"]["flavor"] = 'sec'
```

Comment: Please formulate a real question / post some code to illustrate at what point you're stuck

Answer (score 2):

You can use `collections.defaultdict` for this. A `defaultdict` is given some function used for initializing missing values. In your case, use a recursive `defaultdict` of `defaultdict`.

```
import collections 
infinitedict = lambda: collections.defaultdict(infinitedict)
rule = infinitedict()
```

After putting your stuff into the `defaultdict`, the result will look somewhat like this (though not *exactly* like it, due to `defaultdict` slightly different representation):

```
{'exports-rule-info-2': {
    'security-rules': {
        'security-rule-info': {
            'read-write': {'exports-hostname-info': {'name': 'security_rules '}}, 
            'root': {'exports-hostname-info': {'name': 'security_rules'}}, 
            'sec-flavor': {'sec-flavor-info': {'flavor': 'sec'}}}}, 
    'pathname': 'qtree_name'}}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from collections import defaultdict

tree = lambda: defaultdict(tree)
rule = tree()
rule["exports-rule-info-2"]["pathname"] = qtree_name
rule["exports-rule-info-2"]["security-rules"]["security-rule-info"]["read-write"]["exports-hostname-info"]["name"] = security_rules 
rule["exports-rule-info-2"]["security-rules"]["security-rule-info"]["root"]["exports-hostname-info"]["name"] = security_rules
rule["exports-rule-info-2"]["security-rules"]["security-rule-info"]["sec-flavor"]["sec-flavor-info"]["flavor"] = 'sec'
```

Really though, put some effort into your questions...